# Removing javascript code programmatically from 1500 pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This is regarding my personal site having around 1500 pages. Last year i implemented third party tracking code which is not in use now. I want to remove that code from all the pages programmatically. Can anyone please suggest me a way...how can i go about solving this issue? My site is php/mysql based.

Comment: You're not going to get any answers because you haven't given nearly enough information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This does not have to do with the google analytics api. However, I think the best approach you could take would be to use a software editing tool and doing a search and replace for all the files in your project. Search for the code that you want to remove and replace it with nothing.